# Get latest record after ordering columns based on sequence

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to order my table using two columns in manner of sequence as described:

The current balance to start as the previous balance in next row.

Below is my data

```
ID_DATE     PREV_BAL    CURR_BAL
20200201,   157,        192
20200201,   192,        195
20200201,   123,        124
20200201,   124,        157
20200201,   125,        123
```

And i want it to be ordered first in below sequence

[image]

Then select the top most row as my final result i.e.

```
ID_DATE     PREV_BAL    CURR_BAL
20200201,   192,        195
```

Any assistance

```
with da as (
    select 20200201 id_date, 157 prev_bal, 192 curr_bal from dual
    union all select 20200201 id_date, 192 prev_bal, 195 curr_bal from dual
    union all select 20200201 id_date, 123 prev_bal, 124 curr_bal from dual
    union all select 20200201 id_date, 124 prev_bal, 157 curr_bal from dual
    union all select 20200201 id_date, 125 prev_bal, 123 curr_bal from dual
)
SELECT * FROM da
```

Comment: You should store a full timestamp instead of just date.

Comment: @jarlh i am working on an already existing data of which i cant alter the DB

Comment: If the same PREV_BAL, CURR_BAL combination shows up several times for a date, in different orders, it's impossible to solve this.

Comment: Assume the PREV_BAL, CURR_BAL combination does'nt shows up several times, they are unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [hierarchy](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm), you can see the whole cycle running this query:

```
select da.*, sys_connect_by_path(curr_bal, ' - ') path
  from da 
  connect by prior prev_bal = curr_bal 
  start with not exists (select 1 from da t where t.prev_bal = da.curr_bal)      

 ID_DATE   PREV_BAL   CURR_BAL PATH
-------- ---------- ---------- -------------------------------
20200201        192        195  - 195
20200201        157        192  - 195 - 192
20200201        124        157  - 195 - 192 - 157
20200201        123        124  - 195 - 192 - 157 - 124
20200201        125        123  - 195 - 192 - 157 - 124 - 123
```

But if you want only most parent row just use Tejash's query or `not in` or `not exists`:

```
select * from da 
  where not exists (select 1 from da t where t.prev_bal = da.curr_bal)
```

If you want to go in other direction through all tree, as described in your question, change `connect by clause` and take *leaf row(s)*:

```
select da.*, sys_connect_by_path(curr_bal, ' - ') path
  from da 
  where connect_by_isleaf = 1
  connect by prev_bal = prior curr_bal 
  start with not exists (select 1 from da t where da.prev_bal = t.curr_bal)
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1dcdb08bf3807558bd99edc607f16e22)</sup>**

Comment: Al take this as answer since it answers first part of the question, of ordering as tree because it will help someone when they want to drill down

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing `self outer join` and take the record where it is not able to find any record `CURR_BAL` has any record with the same `PREV_BAL`.

I don't know if it will help you or not, but It is giving the desired answer

Something like the following:

```
with da as (
      select 20200201 id_date, 157 prev_bal, 192 curr_bal from dual
      union all select 20200201 id_date, 192 prev_bal, 195 curr_bal from dual
      union all select 20200201 id_date, 123 prev_bal, 124 curr_bal from dual
      union all select 20200201 id_date, 124 prev_bal, 157 curr_bal from dual
      union all select 20200201 id_date, 125 prev_bal, 123 curr_bal from dual
 )
 -- Your query starts from here
 SELECT
      ID_DATE, PREV_BAL, CURR_BAL
 FROM
     (
          SELECT
              D.*, P.ID_DATE   AS P_ID_DATE
          FROM
              DA D LEFT JOIN DA P ON D.CURR_BAL = P.PREV_BAL
      )
 WHERE P_ID_DATE IS NULL;
```

Result

```
        ID_DATE   PREV_BAL   CURR_BAL
     ---------- ---------- ----------
       20200201        192        195
```

Cheers!!

Comment: A well thought of approach

Answer (score 1):

This was a simple question just use the query below

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
with da as (
    select 20200201 id_date, 157 prev_bal, 192 curr_bal from dual
    union all select 20200201 id_date, 192 prev_bal, 195 curr_bal from dual
    union all select 20200201 id_date, 123 prev_bal, 124 curr_bal from dual
    union all select 20200201 id_date, 124 prev_bal, 157 curr_bal from dual
    union all select 20200201 id_date, 125 prev_bal, 123 curr_bal from dual
)
SELECT * FROM da ORDER BY prev_bal DESC  )
WHERE rownum=1 ORDER BY curr_bal DESC
```

Comment: your soln only works when the values are increasing in value